# Windows 8 HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript App: Set image as background using CSS

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to set the background image of my Windows 8 app. In the CSS for the page I did:

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/logo.png"); 
    background-color: #00522c;
}
```

The background color works but the images does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using what the default template generates, you have a pathing issue (the images directory is not at the same level in the folder hierarchy as the css file)

Try

```
background-image: url("/images/logo.png");
```

or if you want to be really explicit:

```
background-image: url("ms-appx:///images/logo.png");
```